# Logging to a file in pyqt5 application in raspberry pi

Tags: python, logging, pyqt5

I am learning pyqt5. I am trying to implement logging to a file but nothing happens(log file is not created). Here is my code:

```
from homeui import Ui_Form
import logging
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class HomeWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(HomeWindow, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        print('Config Logging') # This is printed
        logging.basicConfig(filename='logs.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        logging.info('Application Started')
        # rest of code left out
```

**EDITS:**
So I have noted that if I change the position at which I import the logging module and declare the basicConfig the code works as expected. I placed the following lines in the top-level above everything else. Any explanation for this behavior.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Comment: You say: *I am trying to implement logging to a file but nothing happens*, but what does *nothing happen* mean? What do you hope to get?

Comment: A log file should be created containing the message being logged

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Apparently there is an occurrence I don't understand. Explained in edits.